# how to use different formats to support different languages

Tags: android, android-resources

In [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html), it says that, to support different languages in your App you should follow the following format:

```
<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]
```

While in my project, I support different languages despite not using the previous format as shown in image-1 below.

(1): please let me know how to use the previous format? and what is the difference between it and the regular format which is as follows

```
values-es-rES
values-es
values-en-rUS
values-fr
```

(2)As shown in image-1, all my supported strings are in one folder which is 'values', and it contains several 'strings.xml' as much as the languages the App supports. Now, what is the difference
between splitting the supported language files across different 'values' files as shown in the previous point, and placing the them inside one 'values' file as shown in image-1?

**image-1**:

[image]

**image-2**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same system but you're not seeing it. Do you see that select in image-1? The one at the top left of the image with "Android" written on it. Click on it and select "Project". Now navigate to your res/values folder.

Comment: ok thanks :), but still it is different from the format stated in my question. the format in my question contains '-b+'..what is this

Comment: Can you post a screen of what you get when you go in the "Project" view?

Comment: ok tomorrow I will post it, but anyways, in the project view, I see something like 'values-en' not <resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]

Comment: please have a look at image-2